# Entering a minor mode with a major mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs

This question may be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253473/emacs-how-do-i-automatically-enter-minor-modes-when-i-enter-a-major-mode), but I can't get the following to work properly in my emacs.

I am trying to enter minor mode `mlint-mode` whenever I enter major mode `matlab-mode` (both modes available at [their SourceForge page](http://matlab-emacs.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/matlab-emacs/matlab-emacs/)). I have the following in my .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'matlab-mode-hook
      (function (lambda()
                  (mlint-mode))))
```

which looks like the answer to the question I linked above. When opening a `.m` file, I get the following error:

> File mode specification error: (void-function mlint-mode)

Could someone please assist in helping me write the correct hook to enter `mlint-mode` when I open a `.m` file? FWIW, I'm running emacs 23.1.50.1.

Comment: Why not just `(add-hook 'matlab-mode-hook 'mlint-mode)`? Are you sure you have actually loaded the minor mode?

Comment: that's the first thing I tried, and it didn't work. see @Lindydancer's answer below..

Comment: You don't do it that way because most minor modes *toggle* their functionality when called with no argument (just like when you call them interactively). So if mlint mode was already enabled for a buffer and you changed to matlab-mode, the above form would have the effect of switching mlint mode *off*. As such, you usually want to pass an argument (frequently 1 or t, but check the appropriate docstring) when enabling a minor mode with a hook function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the correct name is `mlint-minor-mode`. Also, remember to ensure that all matlab stuff is known by Emacs, this can be done using:

```
(require 'matlab-load)
```

As a side note, it is typically a bad idea to use lambda functions in hooks. If you inspect the value of the hook you will see a lot of unrelated things. Also, if you modify your lambda expression and re-add it, both the old and the new version will be on the hook.

Instead, you can do something like:

```
(defun my-matlab-hook ()
   (mlint-minor-mode 1))
(add-hook 'matlab-mode-hook 'my-matlab-hook)
```

The "1" is ensures that mlint mode is turned on or stay on if enabled earlier.